# $A$ is an invertible matrix such that the sum of each row is $1$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let  $A$  be  an $10\times 10$  invertible  matrix  with  real  entries  such  that the  sum  of  each  row  is  $1$. Then

$A$. The  sum  of  entries of  each  row  of  the  inverse  of  $A$  is  $1$

$B$. The  sum  of  entries of  each  column  of  the  inverse  of  $A$  is  $1$

$C$. The  trace  of the  inverse of $A$  is  non-zero

$D$. None  of  the  above

I  don't  see  how  to  proceed or how  to  use  the  sum of  the  elements of of  rows.  Please  help.

I know  option $A$  is  correct  and  option $C$  is not.
Why  is  option $B$  not  correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $x = (1,\dots,1)^T$ (the column vector with ten $1$s).  The fact that the row sum of each matrix of $A$ is $1$ is the same as saying $Ax = x$.

What can we say about $A^{-1}x$?

---

The statement B amounts to saying that $(A^{-1})^Tx = x$ (where $A^T$ is the transpose of $A$).  Note that, in general, $A$ and $A^T$ will *not* have the same eigenvectors.

In particular, consider the example
$$
A = \pmatrix{1/2 & 1/2\\0&1} \implies\\
A^{-1} = \pmatrix{2&-1\\0&1}
$$
We indeed have $A^{-1}x = x$, but not $(A^{-1})^Tx = x$.

Comment: $A^{-1} x$=$x$. $1$ is  an  eigenvalue  of $A$ . What  next ? Sorry  I  still  cannot  get  it.

Comment: Oh I got  it .  Option $A$  is  correct .

Comment: See my latest edit.  Note that the "@" notification system doesn't work in answers.

Answer (score 2):

$C$ is false, by the way. A $2\times 2$ counterexample is $$A = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{array}\right)$$Notice that $A^{-1} = A$ has trace zero. I'll let you come up with a similar $10 \times 10$ example.